# Set character coding when generating xls file with php

Tags: php, sql, excel

How can I set UTF8 character coding with this code?

My problem is that when I open the exported file in Excel, I have to set the encoding manually.

```
$filename = "termekek.xls";

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

        $flag = false;
        $result = mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die('SQL error - '.mysqli_error($kapcs));
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            if(!$flag) 
            {
                echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
                $flag = true;
            }
            array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
            echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
        }
        exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a UTF8 BOM (Byte Order Mark) after sending your headers and before the data:

```
$filename = "termekek.xls";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF8 BOM

$flag = false;
$result = mysqli_query($kapcs, $sql) or die('SQL error - '.mysqli_error($kapcs));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if (!$flag) {
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}

exit();
```